# How is sand blasting different from abrasive jet machining

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining

All I know is sand blasting is used for cleaning and etching purposes and abrasive jet machining (AJM) is used for making cavities and slots. But I think AJM can well also be used for cleaning and etching since it involves spraying abrasive particles just like sand blasting. If thats true isnt sand blasting a type of AJM process? How are they different? Are they different in machining procedure, or the equipment used?

Comment: Is the jet based on water - where have you looked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sand blasting is not a type of AJM because you would never use it to machine anything. Sand blasting would never be used to cut/mahine an intricate shape in a brittle material, the jet does not have enough velocity and has too big a diameter which means it would never be accurate enough for a machining task. It's mainly used just to clean say rust off a casting. And AJM would never be used to clean a thread in a casting because it could potentially damage it.

Answer (score 1):

I think  AJM is water jet blasting with added sand  ; If so, the pressure is 100 to 1000 times higher than routine sand blasting.